# Closing of ZipInputStream works fine in IntelliJ, but fails in Maven with exception

Tags: java, zip

I have a problem. The current code works fine when I run it through IntelliJ,
but it fails with an exception when I run it in maven 3.

```
 public static boolean isZipContent(InputStream inputstream) throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputstream);
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(bis);
    ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
    if (ze == null) {
        return false;
    }
    zis.closeEntry();
    zis.close();
    bis.close();
    return true;
}
```

Exception:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid literal/lengths set
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:193) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:139) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
```

The Zip files look just fine when I open them manually using WinZip or whatever - and as I said, everything works perfectly in IntelliJ.

I have debugged and checked file encoding, class loaders and everything, everything looks equal, but still the code fails consistently if I run the test using Maven3, but works in IntelliJ.

It fails on the zis.closeEntry(); with an exception.
I have made sure the stream is still open during debugging.

I'm using Java 1.6, on Win7. Maven 3.0.4. I've tried other versions of Java with the same result.

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on?

Comment: Are you using the same zip file in both cases?  How did you create it? If you didn't create it with WinZip try creating a zip file with WinZip and using that zip file.  WinZip corrects the zip file whenever possible, so the fact that you can view the zip with WinZip doesn't guarantee that it's a good zip file.

Comment: Yes, it is the same zip file. It is created by some program. Note that this works when running it in IntelliJ, so it is probably not a problem with the zip file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a corrupt Zip file...

What threw me off was that the table of contents with all the entries looked just fine, thus I thought the Zip file was fine.

Once I tried to actually unzip one of the files it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the closeEntry(), as you're not interested in the next one. Remove it. You also don't need bis.close(): it's already closed by zis.close().